# repositories objects in business object methods

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, repository

I thought in the past that my Domain objects shouldn't contain repositories calls in its method. However I faced with following issue. 
I know that domain objects must be always in integrated state.
For example if you have rule that Order can't exist without order line, you need to add orderLine in order constructor and make LineOrder collection read only.

In my case if order moves to Approved state I need to check if Customer has enough money to order and if application can make transfers for this customer and then assoc transfer to order. So my order.Approve method requires to call corresponding repositories methods to check if it is possible to approve an order and get required navigation properties (Order - Transfer association).

If I don't make this checks and assignments in approve method and create approve method in OrderService class (as approve may be considered as process), then my approve method may lead object to not integrated state if someone call it in other code part.

So my questions are:
1. If it is not right to use repositories in domain object methods then how to solve the object's integrity issue above? 
2. If Approve is not process then what is the process in customer, order sample? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should take into consideration that a single entity can have multiple validation contexts.

The answers to your question:
1) You shouldn't use repositories inside your domain models.
2) Approve seems more like a service related concern, not related to your order.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean by multiple validation context? each order state must have separate validation code?

Comment: I mean an Entity class could have different validation rules in different contexts (based on operations performed).

Comment: Please read this post: http://zine.net.pl/blogs/simon/archive/2009/06/24/en-mentoring-ddd-validation.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer, yep, your answer is close to what I've got as final solution, I think that service will have approve method, that will get required transfer and pass it as parameter to order.approve, in this case order will work with its internal state to make some calculations in the approve method, order.approve will have its own validation rules. In such scenario I won't have repository references in order code and order will have integrity.

Comment: Thanks. You know, there is also a DDD yahoo group: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/ .There you can find people with better experience than mine; you can learn a lot just by reading (some) questions and (some) answers and they can offer more complete guidance. Sorry, sounds like a commercial, but it's true.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate and EntitiFramework solves this problem by lazy loading (on demand) the subitems required.

Example

```
 foreach(var transfer in myOrder.Customer.Transfers)
```

By accessing `myOrder.Customer` the customer object is loaded from Database.

By accessing `myOrder.Customer.Transfers` the tranfers-collection is loaded from Database.

This way there is no need to access a repository.

Here is an example how the need for a repository in a business method can be eliminated: [how-to-create-fully-encapsulated-domain-models](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/02/29/how-to-create-fully-encapsulated-domain-models/).